# $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$ implies $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f'(x)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I don't know how to prove the following statement. any help please..

if $f$ is differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f'(x)=1$.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\sin x}{x}=0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since it is not true. Take, for instance, $f(x)=x+\sin(x^2)$. Then you do have $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x=1$. However, $f'(x)=1+2x\cos(x^2)$, and so it is *not* true that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I ask more question? if limx→∞f′(x) exists, is the result the same?

Comment: No. It it exists, it can only be $1$. This follows from the mean value theorem.

Comment: Thank you. If it exists, can I apply the l'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: Yes. That will also work here.